# Cast List type so that one function can take in a more general type of list

Tags: java

Suppose my class hierarchy is as following

```
class Company{
... 
}

class Employee extends Company{
...
}


class Interns extends Company{
...
}

class Test{
   

   private List<Employee> employees;
   private List<Intern> intern;

   // Suppose that multiple objects of Interns and Employees have 
been properly initialized and added to the above two Lists accordingly

   public void process(List<Company> company){
   ...
   }
   
}
```

For my `process()`, I want to be able to use the same function without the need to overload (this is merely an example, I would have more classes, so overloading might seem to be very long).

What should I do so that to the two Lists, so that they can be passed into `process()`? I have tried passing them directly. However, apparently, Java cannot cast `List<Employee>` or `List<Intern>` directly to `List<Company>`

Also, is it better to write multiple overload methods (despite the amount) or try to cast the type so one function will take all.

Comment: Try `public void process(List<? extends Company> company){`

Comment: Why do `Employee` and `Interns` extend `Company`?  An employee is not a company.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the following notation

```
public void process(List<? extends Company> company) {
    // stuff
}
```

Keep in mind that you'll only be able to invoke methods defined in `Company` inside of that method.

See [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) for more information.